# SumProduct, doesn't return me text and number. (Only Number)

Tags: excel, vba

At first thanks to answer)) (It's important for me :p )

I have a number in A3.

When there is this number in column A (Sheet1), per exemple A7 then it will take the value of the cell B7.

```
 =SOMMEPROD(('Sheet1'!A3:A34=Sheet1!A3)*('Sheet1'!B3:B34))
```

I use SOMMEPROD, it's working but only with number, and sometimes I have text and number in my cell (column B).

I already changed the format of the cell but doesn't work.

Thanks a lot)))

Comment: Dear, Thanks) I want to pick up the Value(Number and Text) in the intersection of the column B and the Value of A3 in the column A...

Comment: Then you want a `=vlookup()` not `=sumproduct()`

Comment: pnuts' question still stands: `10 * 15` has a valid answer that 'Sumproduct()' can generate, but what kind of answer do you expect from `edb25 * 252jq`? Excel doesn't do math on text.

Comment: Ok Thanks I will try vlookup)) If I have 20 in A5 I wan the value of B5..))Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying that some of the values in column B are expressed as text, not as a number, probably because they were imported from another source.

if that is the case: First, convert column B into numbers, Then, use sumproduct.

For example, FIRST convert text to values:
in C3 you would enter

```
=value(b3)
```

Then copy that down to from C3 to C34.

Then

```
=SOMMEPROD(('Sheet1'!A3:A34=Sheet1!A3)*('Sheet1'!C3:C34))
```

should have the desired effect.

Note that you sometime get #N/A errors with the "value" function, for example if there are unexpected spaces.  To be safe, rather than using value alone, try this:

```
= iferror(value(B3),0)
```

or to be more creative you can try:

```
= iferror(value(substitute(B3," ","")),0)  ' deletes all spaces
= iferror(value(substitute(substitute(b3,char(160),"")," ","")),0)  
'deletes all spaces and "nonbreaking spaces" copied from a web page
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to use SumProduct for. There's two main reasons this function shows up. Those are:

- To sum the product of two ranges.
- To sum a range of numbers that meet multiple criteria. This relies on that `True = 1` and `False = 0` so when want to find the combined weight of blue dogs in some cells, your formula might look like `=SUMPRODUCT(1*($A$1:$A$50 = "Blue"), 1*($B$1:$B$50 = "Dog"), $C$1:$C$50)`. Note the `1*` which guarantees the formula will know how to multiply the results. After all, `True` and `False` don't multiply. Their binary representations (1 and 0) though, do.

NB though that people also sometimes remember it as a lookup formula because of the second use, and therefore expect to be able to get text back. Such approaches are an easy misunderstanding to end up with, but really there you want to use an `INDEX(<Result Array>,MATCH(1,INDEX(1 * (FIRST CONDITION) * (SECOND CONDITION) * (AND SO ON),,),0)`. This approach basically gives you an array formula without CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER (it's not faster, but because the condition is in an index formula, it works), and your conditions can be arbitrary (the same way as for sumproduct). But it'll give you the FIRST result, not the sum of all of them.

Hope that helps.

Edit: Crossed my mind, you might be expecting `A1` to contain `Erp` and `B1` to contain `54`, and in `C1` you want `Erp54`. This doesn't even need a function - just the `&` operator, which joins two strings together - so in `C1`, you'd just put `=A1 & B1`. And you're done.